# Applicative instance for MaybeT m assumes Monad m

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, applicative, haxl

I've been using the `Haxl` monad (described here: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1le4y5/the_haxl_project_at_facebook_slides_from_my_talk), which has the interesting feature that `<*>` for its Applicative instance isn't the same as `ap` from Control.Monad.  This is a key feature that allows it to do concurrent computations without blocking.  For example, if `hf` and `ha` are long computations, then

```
let hf :: Haxl (a -> b) = ...
    ha :: Haxl a = ...
in do
  f <- hf
  a <- ha
  return (f a)
```

will do them sequentially, while

```
hf <*> ha
```

will do them in parallel and then combine the results.

I would like to be able to run computations in `MaybeT Haxl`, but the problem is that the Applicative instance for `MaybeT m` in the transformers package uses monadic bind:

```
instance (Functor m, Monad m) => Applicative (MaybeT m) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

Where `ap = liftM2 id` is from `Control.Monad`. This makes

```
let hmf :: MaybeT Haxl (a -> b) = ...
    hma :: MaybeT Haxl a = ...
in hmf <*> hma
```

run sequentially.  It seems like a better instance would be more like

```
instance (Applicative m) => Applicative (MaybeT m) where
    pure = MaybeT . pure . Just
    MaybeT f <*> MaybeT x = MaybeT $ (<*>) <$> f <*> x
```

(Here, `(<*>)` on the right-hand side is for the `Maybe` monad, while the non-parenthesized `<*>` on the right-hand side is for `m`.)  Note that the context is different -- the above instance assumes only `Applicative m`, while the instance in transformers assumes `Functor m, Monad m`.

My main question is practical: what should I do about this?  Should I roll my own `MaybeT` monad transformer?  Is there some way to get around the "Duplicate instance declarations" complaint that ghc gives me if I try to write the above?

I'd also like to know: is the current setup a design flaw in the transformers package?  If not, why not?

Comment: Everyone tends to assume that superclass implementations match subclass implementations exactly. Haxl is violating this unwritten rule and thus can't play nicely with others. Transformers is also assuming you're making `Monad` transformers, thus its implementation. `Applicative` "transformers" have much nicer structure.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson, this is not a rule, written or otherwise. Nor is this the only case where `<*>` is better, in some significant way, than `ap`. It seems to me that `MaybeT` is in the wrong here.

Comment: After [AMP](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) is wide-spread as part of GHC 7.10, we could rewrite `Applicative (MaybeT m)` definition. currently `Applicative` isn't a superclass of `Monad`, so you might break lots of packages. Also I see surprisingly many *Foo is instance of Monad but not of Applicative* warnings still. Would suggest to write your own `MaybeT` for now - or maybe make a PR to `transformers`?.

Comment: @dfeuer It tends to be an unwritten rule. People frequently assume you can just switch out do syntax and `(<*>)` syntax as convenient and pretty. Once AMP lands this will be even stronger, but it'll also be pretty easy to switch out this definition with the Pplicative only one.

Comment: Actually it's a written rule – it's right there in the [Control.Applicative documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html)

Comment: @BenMillwood I agree with dfeuer. The most natural way of reading the rules you mention is as extensional equalities (i.e. same results for the same arguments), which do not forbid an `ap` that happens to be less efficient than `(<*>)` (cf. the remarks on `(*>)` a few lines above in the documentation, as well as [this GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11128)). Thankfully, the AMP is now a reality and `MaybeT` was fixed in the way phadej alludes to. Still, this is a neat example of why it is better not to instantiate `Applicative` in terms of `Monad`.

Answer (score 7):

The trick is that (unlike monads) applicative functors are composable, so you don't need (applicative) transformers such as `MaybeT`. Instead, you can use `Compose` to combine two applicative functors together:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Compose

type HaxlM = Compose Haxl Maybe

-- if you prefer to have a function for constructing values:
haxlM :: Haxl (Maybe a) -> HaxlM a
haxlM = Compose
```

The composition is always a proper instance of `Applicative` and use only the `Applicative` instance of their components. For example:

```
test = getZipList . getCompose
       $ (+) <$> Compose (ZipList [Just 1,  Nothing, Just 3])
             <*> Compose (ZipList [Nothing, Just 20, Just 30])
```

produces `[Nothing,Nothing,Just 33]`.

Comment: Ok, cool. But in this case I couldn't also use monad operations, right? (A general Haxl computation uses both applicative and monad to represent different data flows.) Is there some way to get the best of both worlds (i.e. a HaxlM monad with ap != <*>, without writing one from scratch)?

Comment: @davidsd I guess no. You could perhaps use `FlexibleInstances`/`FlexibleContexts` to create a monad instance for `Compose Haxl Maybe`, but then it's probably better to rather create the `HaxlM` monad from scratch.

Comment: As long as we're on this path, it's worth noting that `Applicative` products are also `Applicative`. Same with `Applicative` sums so long as there's a natural transformation which lets bias work: http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/