# Why should Applicative be a superclass of Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, fam-proposal

Given:

```
Applicative m, Monad m => mf :: m (a -> b), ma :: m a
```

it seems to be considered a law that:

```
mf <*> ma === do { f <- mf; a <- ma; return (f a) }
```

or more concisely:

```
(<*>) === ap
```

The [documentation for `Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) says that `<*>` is "sequential application," and that suggests that `(<*>) = ap`. This means that `<*>` must evaluate effects sequentially from left to right, for consistency with `>>=`... But that feels wrong. [McBride and Paterson's original paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf) seems to imply that the left-to-right sequencing is arbitrary:

> The IO monad, and indeed any Monad, can be made Applicative by taking `pure` =
>   `return` and `<*>` = `ap`. *We could alternatively use the variant of `ap` that performs
>   the computations in the opposite order*, but we shall keep to the left-to-right order
>   in this paper.

So there are *two* lawful, non-trivial derivations for `<*>` that follow from `>>=` and `return`, with distinct behavior. And in some cases, *neither* of these two derivations are desirable.

For example, the `(<*>) === ap` law forces [Data.Validation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-0.3.4/docs/Data-Validation.html) to define two distinct data types: `Validation` and `AccValidation`. The former has a `Monad` instance similar to [ExceptT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html), and a consistent `Applicative` instance which is of limited utility, since it stops after the first error. The latter, on the other hand, doesn't define a `Monad` instance, and is therefore free to implement an `Applicative` that, much more usefully, accumulates errors.

There's been some [discussion about this previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211776/why-isnt-validation-a-monad-scalaz7) on StackOverflow, but I don't think it really got to the meat of the question:

### Why should this be a law?

The other laws for functors, applicatives and monads—such as identity, associativity, etc.—express some fundamental, mathematical properties of those structures. We can implement various optimizations using these laws and prove things about our own code using them. In contrast, it feels to me like the `(<*>) === ap` law imposes an arbitrary constraint with no corresponding benefit.

For what it's worth, I'd prefer to ditch the law in favor of something like this:

```
newtype LeftA m a = LeftA (m a)
instance Monad m => Applicative (LeftA m) where
  pure = return
  mf <*> ma = do { f <- mf; a <- ma; return (f a) }

newtype RightA m a = RightA (m a)
instance Monad m => Applicative (RightA m) where
  pure = return
  mf <*> ma = do { a <- ma; f <- mf; return (f a) }
```

I think that correctly captures the relationship between the two, without unduly constraining either.

So, a few angles to approach the question from:

- Are there any other laws relating `Monad` and `Applicative`?
- Is there any inherent mathematical reason for effects to sequence for `Applicative` in the same way that they do for `Monad`?
- Does GHC or any other tool perform code transformations that assume/require this law to be true?
- Why is the [Functor-Applicative-Monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) proposal considered such an overwhelmingly good thing? (Citations would be much appreciated here).

And one bonus question:

- How do `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` fit in to all this?

---

Note: major edit to clarify the meat of the question. Answer posted by @duplode quotes an earlier version.

Comment: The order of evaluation of `<*>` is not important if the applicative is not effectful. But if it is also a (non trivial) monad, then it must be effectful. You could do something stupid like throw away effects from the left arguement, but if you have a monad, `ap` is a "natural" definition for `<*>`. But there is no inherent need requirements for the ordering of effects for applicatives, whereas there obviously is for monads.

Comment: "if you have a monad, `ap` is a "natural" definition for `<*>`." I'd suggest it's *one of two* possible natural derivations, the choice between which is arbitrary.

Comment: ... And, I should say, in some cases I don't necessarily want either of these two derivations, but a distinct implementation entirely (as in `AccValidation`).

Comment: You would probably be interested in [`Control.Applicative.Backwards`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html)

Comment: On the `LeftA`/`RightA` idea: there are comparable cases elsewhere in the standard libraries (e.g. `Sum` and `Product` in `Data.Monoid`). The problem of doing the same with `Applicative` is that the power-to-weight relation is too low to justify the extra precision/flexibility. The `newtype`s would make applicative style a lot less pleasant to use. That you can easily recover the `RightA` instance from the `LeftA` one (ergo `Backwards` and `(<**>)`) only compounds the issue.

Comment: doesn't HAXL use a fundamentally different Applicative instance than Monad instance? (source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73B1uc3xkvo   it's been a while). that might be relevant.

Comment: @samboosalis Not fundamentally different, in the sense that even though `(<*>)` is more efficient than `ap` they give the same results, and therefore they do not violate the guideline under consideration here. For further discussion, see [this question about the Haxl instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22750315/2751851).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I'm not terribly satisfied with the answers given so far, but I think the comments attached to them are a bit more compelling. So I'll summarize here:

---

I think there's only one sensible `Functor` instance that follows from `Applicative`:

```
fmap f fa = pure f <*> fa
```

Assuming that's unique, it makes sense that `Functor` should be a superclass of `Applicative`, with that law. Likewise, I think there's only one sensible `Functor` instance that follows from `Monad`:

```
fmap f fa = fa >>= return . f
```

So again, it makes sense that `Functor` should be a superclass of `Monad`. The objection I had (and, really, still have) is that there are two sensible `Applicative` instances that follow from `Monad` and, in some specific instances, even more that are lawful; so why mandate one?

[pigworker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker) (first author on the [original `Applicative` paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/%7Eross/papers/Applicative.pdf)) writes:

> "Of course it doesn't follow. It's a choice."
>
> (on [twitter](https://twitter.com/pigworker/status/475893577315516416)): "do-notation is unjust punishment for working in a monad; we deserve applicative notation"

[duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) similarly writes:

> "... it is fair to say that `pure === return` and `(<*>) === ap` aren't laws in the strong sense that e.g. the monad laws are so ..."
>
> "On the `LeftA`/`RightA` idea: there are comparable cases elsewhere in the standard libraries (e.g. `Sum` and `Product` in `Data.Monoid`). The problem of doing the same with `Applicative` is that the power-to-weight relation is too low to justify the extra precision/flexibility. The newtypes would make applicative style a lot less pleasant to use."

So, I'm happy to see that choice stated explicitly, justified by the simple reasoning that it makes the most common cases easier.

Comment: `Functor` instances are indeed unique. You can use free theorems to [prove](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/15384) that, modulo non-termination shenanigans, all law-abiding implementations of `fmap` for a type constructor do the same thing.

Comment: I love "do-notation is unjust punishment for working in a monad; we deserve applicative notation".

Answer (score 9):

Among other things, you ask why is the `Functor-Applicative-Monad` proposal a good thing.  One reason is because the lack of unity means there is a lot of duplication of API. Consider the standard `Control.Monad` module.  The following are the functions in that module that essentially use the `Monad` (there are none for `MonadPlus`) constraint:

```
(>>=) fail (=<<) (>=>) (<=<) join foldM foldM_
```

The following are the functions in that module where a `Monad`/`MonadPlus` constraint could as far as I can tell easily be relaxed to `Applicative`/`Alternative`:

```
(>>) return mzero mplus mapM mapM_ forM forM_ sequence sequence_ forever
msum filterM mapAndUnzipM zipWithM zipWithM_ replicateM replicateM_ guard
when unless liftM liftM2 liftM3 liftM4 liftM5 ap
```

Many of the latter group *do* have `Applicative` or `Alternative` versions, in either `Control.Applicative`, `Data.Foldable` or `Data.Traversable` – but why need to learn all that duplication in the first place?

Comment: This seems more a matter of convenience than correctness. It seems natural that `Functor` should be a superclass of both `Monad` (where `fmap f fa === fa >>= return . f`) and `Applicative` (where `fmap f fa === pure f <*> fa`). It also makes sense that `return === pure`, so it follows that `fa >>= pure . f === pure f <*> fa`. But I don't think it follows that `<*> === ap`.

Comment: Of course it doesn't follow. It's a choice. Why do you think it's a bad choice? When is it good to make the obvious Moggi-style translation of the applicative notation a dangerous misreading?

Comment: In many cases it's not a bad choice; as most have noted, it's the obvious choice! But that alone doesn't feel like sufficient grounds for a law; it still seems like a choice best made case-by-case. My favorite example again: a `Validation` data type with an `Applicative` instance that accumulates errors in a semigroup and a `Monad` instance that does not. I don't see why there should be a law forbidding this.

Comment: @mergeconflict Consistency, understandability, simplicity and API streamlining. Taking all of that into account, an extra type for the special cases in which you want something other than the obvious instance is a small price to pay. Given a well-designed library, it will be painless to switch between the instances if need be - your example package, for instance, provides convenient isomorphisms between `Validation`, `AccValidation` and `Either`.

Answer (score 6):

> and in my own (perhaps mistaken) intuition, given `pure f <*> ma <*> mb`, there needn't be any predetermined sequencing since none of the values depend on each other.

The values don't, but the effects do. `(<*>) :: t (a -> b) -> t a -> t b` means that you have to somehow combine the effects of the arguments in order to get the overall effects. Whether the combination will be commutative or not depends on how the instance is defined. For example, the instance for `Maybe` is commutative, while the default, "cross join" instance  for lists isn't. Therefore, there are cases in which you can't avoid imposing *some* order.

> What are the laws, if any, relating Monad and Applicative?

While it is fair to say that `pure === return` and `(<*>) === ap` (quoting [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:1)) aren't laws in the strong sense that e.g. the monad laws are so, they help keeping the instances unsurprising. Given that every `Monad` gives rise to an instance of `Applicative` (actually two instances, as you point out), it is natural that the actual instance of `Applicative` matches what `Monad` gives us. As for the left-to-right convention, following [the order of `ap` and `liftM2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259453/2751851) (which already existed back when `Applicative` was introduced, and which mirror the order imposed by `(>>=)`) was a sensible decision. (Note that, if we ignored for a moment how much `(>>=)` matters in practice, the opposite choice would be defensible as well, as it would make `(<*>)` and `(=<<)`, which have analogous types, sequence effects in the same order.)

> Does GHC or any other tool perform code transformations that assume/require this law to be true?

That sounds very unlikely given that `Applicative` isn't even a superclass of `Monad`([yet](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)). These "laws", however, allow readers of the code to make the transformations, which matters just as much.

N.B.: If you need to reverse the sequencing of effects in an `Applicative` instance, there is [`Control.Applicative.Backwards`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html), as Gabriella Gonzalez has pointed out. Also, [`(<**>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--42--62-) flips the arguments but still sequences effects from left to right, so it can also be used to reverse sequencing. Similarly, `(<*)` is not `flip (*>)`, as both sequence effects from left to right.

Comment: I just submitted a pretty big edit to attempt to clarify my question... It's really less about why choose left-to-right over right-to-left, and more: why relate `Monad` and `Applicative` in this way at all? I can imagine providing a pair of `newtypes` à la `Control.Applicative.Backwards` that provide instances of `<*>` based on `>>=`, but making `Applicative` a superclass of `Monad` seems too strong.

Comment: @mergeconflict The mathematical relationship goes in the other direction: `return` and `ap` follow the applicative laws, just like both `\f u -> pure f <*> u` and `\f m -> m >>= return . f` follow the functor laws. The Applicative-Monad Proposal reflects those facts. Now, if multiple instances are possible only one of them will be canonical, the others being relegated to `newtype`s. The simplest choice is picking the matching set of instances. It makes it easier to reason about code, and may even give instances for free (e.g. by starting with `Monad`and then defining `(<*>) = ap`, etc).

Comment: The fact that you get instances for free is great, but only to the extent that they're the instances you *want*. If parametricity gives you an instance that's really the only sensible one—as it does when deriving `Functor`, for example—then that's a safe bet. That's not the case here, so although one instance seems more obvious than others, that still doesn't feel sufficient to enforce it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the answer to the question in the title is: consider

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f, Traversable t => t (f a) -> f (t a)
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

What is the type of `join . sequenceA`?

1. ATP: `Monad m, Traversable m => m (m a) -> m a`
2. Current situation: `Applicative m, Monad m, Traversable m => m (m a) -> m a`

Granted, `join . sequenceA` is a contrived situation, but there are certainly cases where you *need* a monad, but you'd also like to use the `Applicative` operations `<*>`, `*>`, `<*`, `<**>`, etc.  Then:

- Having two separate constraints to capture both operations is annoying.
- The `Applicative` names is (IMHO) nicer than those of the traditional monad operations.
- Having two different names, e.g. `ap`, `>>`, `<<`, etc., is annoying ("oh, you can't use `<*>` there, that's a `Monad` not an `Applicative`"; "oh, you have to use `<*>` there, that's an `Applicative` not a `Monad`").
- In real monads, the order is *really, really* important, which means that if `>>` and `*>` do different things, then you can't actually use the `Applicative` syntax, because it'll do something you don't expect.

So, pragmatically, having an `Applicative` for every `Monad` which is compatible with it (in the `(<*>) = ap` sense) is a really, really good idea.