# Why can AccValidation not have a Monad instance?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

From the documentation of the [`validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation) package:

> The `AccValidation` data type is isomorphic to `Either`, but has an instance of `Applicative` that accumulates on the error side. That is to say, if two (or more) errors are encountered, they are appended using a `Semigroup` operation.
>
> As a consequence of this `Applicative` instance, there is no corresponding `Bind` or `Monad` instance. `AccValidation` is an example of, "An applicative functor that is not a monad."

It isn't evident to me why this is a consequence. I can imagine a `Monad` instance for `AccValidation` that behaves like `Either` - What would make this unlawful?

Comment: What instance do you imagine? Note that the applicative instance for `Either` accumulates on the non-error side.

Comment: You can't to run later "stages" if an earlier stage failed. With Applicative, you can still *compute* the later stages even if you can't apply them to get a successful result (and thus you can know if the computation of the later stages failed). With Monad, each stage returns the next one, so you don't even know what the later stages are supposed to be.

Comment: @Alec The applicative for `Either` doesn't "accumulate" *at all* in the same sense that `AccValidation` accumulates, right?

Comment: @ChrisMartin While `ap = (<*>)` is part of the contract of the `Monad` class, as stated by the documentation you linked to, it isn't, strictly speaking, a monad law -- it's just that it would be horribly confusing if it didn't hold. Here is a [highly relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24112786/2751851), with answers and comments that approach the issue from many different perspectives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mechanically, the `Either`-ish `Monad` instance for `AccValidation` would be

```
-- The (Monoid err) context is not used for anything, 
-- it's just there to satisfy the Applicative super-instance
instance (Monoid err) => Monad (AccValidation err) where
    return = AccSuccess
    AccFailure err >>= f = AccFailure err
    AccSuccess x >>= f = f x
```

which would mean we have

```
AccFailure err1 <*> AccFailure err2 = AccFailure (err1 <> err2)
AccFailure err1 `ap` AccFailure err2 = AccFailure err1
```

which breaks the monad law of `<*> = ap`.

Intuitively, it can't be made a monad because in a monad, the effect (i.e. the validation failures) of a computation can depend on previously bound results. But in the case of a failure, there is no result. So `Either` has no choice than to short-circuit to failure in that case, since there is nothing to feed to the subsequent functions on right-hand sides of `(>>=)`s.

This is in stark contrast to applicative functors, where the effect (in this case, the validation failures) cannot depend on other results, which is why we can get all validation failures without having to feed results (where would they come from?) from one computation to the other.

Comment: isn't `ap` just an alias for `<*>` like `fmap/<$>`?

Comment: @notgiorgi Not exactly. [`ap` is `(<*>)` implemented using the `Monad` methods](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#ap). `ap` is to `(<*>)` what `liftM` is to `fmap`.

Answer (score 10):

[The `(<*>) = ap` exigence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) can be stated explicitly in terms of `(>>=)`:

```
u <*> v = u >>= \f -> fmap f v -- [1]
```

Now, given the `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for `AccValidation`, we have:

```
fmap _ (AccFailure e) = AccFailure e -- [2]

AccFailure e1 <*> AccFailure e2 = AccFailure (e1 <> e2) -- [3]
```

If we make `u = AccFailure e1` and `v = AccFailure e2` in [1], we get:

```
AccFailure e1 <*> AccFailure e2 = AccFailure e1 >>= \f -> fmap f (AccFailure e2)
```

Substituting [2] and [3] into that leads us to:

```
AccFailure (e1 <> e2) = AccFailure e1 >>= \_ -> AccFailure e2 -- [4]
```

The problem is that it is impossible to write a `(>>=)` such that [4] holds. The left-hand side depends on an `e2` value which must originate, on the right-hand side, from applying `\_ -> AccFailure e2 :: Semigroup e => a -> AccValidation e b`. However, there is nothing to which it can be applied -- in particular, `e1` has the wrong type. (See the final two paragraphs of Cactus' answer for further discussion of this point.) Therefore, there is no way of giving `AccValidation` a `Monad` instance which is consistent with its `Applicative` one.