# Could the `Applicative` instance for `These` preserve more "failure" information?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm looking at the [`These`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.2/docs/Data-These.html#t:These) datatype from the [these](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.2) package, in particular at its [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.2/docs/src/Data.These.html#line-272) instance:

```
instance (Semigroup a) => Applicative (These a) where
    pure = That
    This  a   <*> _         = This a
    That    _ <*> This  b   = This b
    That    f <*> That    x = That (f x)
    That    f <*> These b x = These b (f x)
    These a _ <*> This  b   = This (a <> b)
    These a f <*> That    x = These a (f x)
    These a f <*> These b x = These (a <> b) (f x)
```

If one of the `These` is a `This`, the result is always `This`. However, there seems to be a certain assymetry.

Here, if the second component is a `These` constructor, its information is completely discarded:

```
    This  a   <*> _         = This a
```

here the first component is a `These` constructor, but the `a` part is preserved in the result.

```
These a _ <*> This  b   = This (a <> b)
```

Testing it in ghci:

```
ghci> This "a" <*> These "b" True
This "a"
ghci> These "a" not <*> This "b"
This "ab"
```

But what if we added a case at the beginning like

```
This  a <*> These b _    = This (a <> b)
```

Would that break the `Applicative` laws?

Comment: Interesting observation. My guess is that the `Applicative` instance has to be biased in this way to be compatible with the `Monad` one, and that a different, more symmetrical, instance should be possible, along the lines of what [`Validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-1.1.2/docs/Data-Validation.html) is for `Either`. (I haven't thought it through yet, though.)

Comment: The monad instance needs to define ` This  a >>= g`, and there's no way to call `g` here, so the only sensible result is `This a`. I guess this forces the bias mentioned by duplode. Perhaps we could also have a non-monad variant of `These` which is more symmetrical. Anyway, you could try to run QuickCheck on the applicative laws just for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed instance is lawful. One way of showing that is by approximating `These` by a pair of maybes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GHC2021, LambdaCase, PatternSynonyms #-}
import Data.These
import Data.Functor.Product
import Data.Functor.Const

newtype NotQuiteThese a b = NQT (Product (Const (Maybe a)) Maybe b)
    deriving (Show, Functor, Applicative)

pattern Neither = NQT (Pair (Const Nothing) Nothing)
pattern This' a = NQT (Pair (Const (Just a)) Nothing)
pattern That' b = NQT (Pair (Const Nothing) (Just b))
pattern These' a b = NQT (Pair (Const (Just a)) (Just b))

theseToNqt :: These a b -> NotQuiteThese a b
theseToNqt = \case
    This a -> This' a
    That b -> That' b
    These a b -> These' a b

-- nqtToThese . theseToNqt = Just
nqtToThese :: NotQuiteThese a b -> Maybe (These a b)
nqtToThese = \case
    Neither -> Nothing
    This' a -> Just (This a)
    That' b -> Just (That b)
    These' a b -> Just (These a b)
```

`NotQuiteThese` is not isomorphic to `These` because of the superfluous `Neither` case. For our current purposes, though, that is not a problem: the encoding used here gives rise to an `instance Semigroup a => Applicative (NotQuiteThese a)` which is equivalent to your proposed instance as far as the non-`Neither` cases are concerned. (The first `Maybe` lifts the semigroup to a monoid, `Const` further lifts it to an applicative functor, and [the product of applicatives is applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Product.html#line-86).) Below is a quick demonstration:

```
ghci> nqtToThese $ theseToNqt (These "foo" (2*)) <*> theseToNqt (This "bar")
Just (This "foobar")
ghci> nqtToThese $ theseToNqt (This "foo") <*> theseToNqt (These "bar" 7)
Just (This "foobar")
```

The asymmetry in the canonical instance for `These` is imposed for the sake of compatibility with the `Monad` instance, so that `(<*>) = ap` holds. The unavoidable `This a >>= _ = This a` clause means `ap (This a) _ = This a`. This situation is analogous to [the contrast between `Either` and its error-accumulating variant, `Validation`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40539650/2751851).

On a final note, if a `These`-plus-`Neither` type is ever necessary for practical purposes, you can use [`Can` from the *smash* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/smash-0.1.3/docs/Data-Can.html) -- as long as you don't mind `Can` having a `Monad` instance and thus an asymmetric `Applicative` as well.