# Why does 'for' from Data.Traversable accept monadic actions?

Tags: haskell, traversable

I was working on the following small fragment of code:

```hs
import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap
import           Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import           GHC.Generics

-- definitions of Whitelisted, WhitelistComment and their FromJSON instances
-- omitted for brevity

data Whitelist = Whitelist
  { whitelist :: Map Whitelisted WhitelistComment
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance FromJSON Whitelist where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    fmap (Whitelist . Map.fromList) . forM (HashMap.toList v) $ \(a, b) -> do
      a' <- parseJSON (String a)
      b' <- parseJSON b
      return (a', b')
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

when I realised that I can rewrite the `do` block in applicative style:

```hs
instance FromJSON Whitelist where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    fmap (Whitelist . Map.fromList) . forM (HashMap.toList v) $ \(a, b) ->
      (,) <$> parseJSON (String a) <*> parseJSON b
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

and with that I could also replace `forM` with `for`. Before making the change above I switched to `for` first:

```hs
instance FromJSON Whitelist where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    fmap (Whitelist . Map.fromList) . for (HashMap.toList v) $ \(a, b) -> do
      a' <- parseJSON (String a)
      b' <- parseJSON b
      return (a', b')
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

and to my surprise this still compiled. Given the definition of  [`for`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:for):

```hs
for :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t a -> (a -> f b) -> f (t b)
```

I thought the `Applicative` constraint would prevent me from using do notation / return in the action passed to `for`.

I'm clearly missing something fundamental here, either in terms of what `for` signature really implies, or how the code I posted is interpreted by the compiler, and would appreciate any help understanding what's going on.

Comment: Are you missing that [`Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112786/why-should-applicative-be-a-superclass-of-monad)? `forM`, `liftM`, etc. are reminders from when `Applicative` wasn't (in the Prelude) a superclass of `Monad`.

Comment: @Alec isn't that the other way around? Meaning that I could pass the code in applicative style into forM without any changes, but not in the opposite direction? I'm not quite sure how it would be possible to use `return` when `Applicative` constraint is present.

Comment: `parseJSON` works in the `Parser` monad, which is also an applicative (of course). `return` (and do notation) checks `Parser` is a monad -- it is. `for` checks it is also an applicative -- it is. Everything works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first short answer is that [`Parser`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Parser) has an `Applicative` instance. The snippet

```
do
  a' <- parseJSON a
  b' <- parseJSON b
  return (a', b')
```

has the type `Parser (Whitelisted, WhitelistComment)` which unifies with `f b` in the type signature

```
for :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t a -> (a -> f b) -> f (t b)
```

Since there's an `Applicative Parser` instance, it also satisfies that constraint. (I think I got the types for `a'` and `b'` right)

---

The second short answer is that a `Monad` is strictly more powerful than an `Applicative`, anywhere you need an `Applicative` you can use a `Monad` instead. Ever since the [`Monad`-`Applicative` proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) was implemented, *every* `Monad` is also `Applicative`. The [`Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) class now looks like

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where 
    ...
```

A `Monad` is strictly more powerful than an `Applicative`, anywhere you need an `Applicative` you can use a `Monad` instead with the following substitutions:

- [ap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) instead of `<*>`
- `return` instead of `pure`
- [`liftM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) instead of `fmap`

If you're writing some new type, `SomeMonad`, and have provided an instance for the `Monad` class you can use it to provide the instances for `Applicative` and `Functor` too.

```
import Control.Monad

instance Applicative SomeMonad where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Functor SomeMonad where
    fmap = liftM
```

Comment: Thank you. I see how `Monad` is more powerful and that with AMP every `Monad` is an `Applicative` as well. But when a signature says it specifically wants an `Applicative` wouldn't that mean that it wants to restrict those powers and only work with `Applicative` interface?

Comment: Yes, `for` is only permitted to use the `Applicative` powers of the object you pass in. But you can use monadic powers to construct values of that type - how you do stuff inside your lambda is a black box to `for`.

Comment: @amalloy I think I got it now - `for` doesn't care how the value was produced, only that it satisfies the `Applicative` constraint. I thought that the `Applicative` restriction would be imposed on what the lambda itself can do, not just on what it returns.

Comment: And it seems the crucial thing I missed was *producing* an `Applicative` vs *working* with one :-(

Comment: @ppb It's not about _producing_ vs _working_ with a type. It's about what you (and the type system) know about the type. When you call `for :: forall f.  ...` you are passing `for` both its arguments and the type `f`. You know more about `f` than it's an `Applicative f` or a `Monad f`; you know what `f` is! It's `Parser`. You can use anything you know about the type, including crazy things that aren't even a part of either `Applicative` or `Monad`, like `parseJSON` (which you're already using). If you know that `f` is `Parser` to use `parseJSON`, you also know it's a `Monad` to use `>>=`.

Answer (score 6):

This is just the usual caller-vs-implementer duality going on, where one side gets flexibility and the other restriction.

`for` provides you with this interface:

```
for :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t a -> (a -> f b) -> f (t b)
```

You as the caller get the flexibility to choose any type `f` to instantiate it, so you can use it as if it were:

```
for :: Traversable t => t a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser (t b)
```

Clearly once you've done that, there's no reason you couldn't use any `Parser`-specific functionality in the function you pass to `for`, including `Monad` stuff.

The *implementer* of `for` on the other hand gets restricted by the polymorphism in the interface of `for`. They have to work with **any** choice of `f`, so they can *only* use the `Applicative` interface in the code they write to implement `for`. But that only restricts the code of `for` itself, not the function passed into it.

If the author of `for` wanted to restrict what the caller could do in that function, they could have used `RankNTypes` to instead provide this interface:

```
for :: forall t f. (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t a -> (forall g. Applicative g => a -> g b) -> f (t b)
```

Now the provided lambda itself must be polymorphic in `g` (subject to an `Applicative` constraint). The caller of `for` still gets the flexibility to choose `f`, with the implementer being restricted in using only `Applicative` features. But the caller of `for` is the **implementer** of the function argument, so now that that function is polymorphic itself the caller of `for` is restricted to using only `Applicative` features there and the implementer of `for` gets the freedom to use it with any type they like (including possibly using monad features to combine it with other internal values). With this specific type signature the implementer of `for` will have to choose to instantiate `g` with the same type the caller of `for` selected for `f`, in order to come up with the final `f (t b)` return value. But the caller of `for` would still be restricted by the type system to providing a function that works for any `Applicative g`.

The point is, if you get to choose what type to instantiate a polymorphic signature with then you are not the one restricted by that interface. You can choose a type and then use whatever other features of that type you like, provided you still do provide the bits of information the interface requires of you. i.e. You can use non-`Traversable` functionality to create your `t a` and non-`Applicative` functionality to create your `a -> f b`, all that's required is that you do provide those inputs. And indeed you almost *have* to make use of functionality specific to `a` and `b`. The *implementer* of the polymorphic signature doesn't get that freedom, they are restricted by the polymorphism to only doing things that would work for any possible choice.

As an aside, similarly to how rank 2 types add "another level" of this duality with the roles reversed (and rank N types allow arbitrarily many levels), a similar duality is also seen (flipped around again) in the constraints themselves. Consider again the signature:

```
for :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t a -> (a -> f b) -> f (t b)
```

The *caller* of `for` is restricted by the `Traversable` and `Applicative` constraints when choosing the types `t` and `f`. The implementer gets the freedom to use any functions implied by those constraints, without worrying about how to prove the constraints are satisfied.