# What is the point of the Functor -> Applicative -> Monad hierarchy

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative, default-method

What is the point of making Functor a super class of Applicative and Monad. Both Applicative and Monad immediately imply the only implementation of Functor that abides by the laws as far as I can tell. But rather I have to type out the same implementation of Functor every time. Is there a way to avoid doing this?

Further more Monad implies the only implementation of Applicative that abides by the laws so why make Applicative a super class of Monad? Again it makes implementing Applicative for new data types redundant.

Is there a way to make a Monad without having to implement Applicative and Functor (as its operations are already the most general). And to make an Applicative without having to implement Functor.

I see the benefit of the class hierarchy as what I just said explains the "is a" relation between them. But at the same time having to implement each is annoying. I just want to define `return` and `>>=` and get all the operations of all 3 back.

Comment: Related: [*Why should Applicative be a superclass of Monad?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24112786/2751851)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get those instances this way:

```
import Control.Applicative
data Whatever a = {- ... -} deriving (Functor, Applicative) via (WrappedMonad Whatever)
```

It would have been nice to add `DefaultSignatures` defaults to the `Functor` and `Applicative` classes at the time the compiler broke from the spec, so that you wouldn't even need to write `via WrappedMonad`, but now that it's done I suspect we'll never get them. Too bad.

Comment: Please don't derive `Functor` via `WrappedMonad`. Much better to `stock` derive it. (And for `Applicative` it's also always worth considering to implement the instance directly, instead of piggy-backing on the `Monad` one which may well be less efficient.)

Comment: `Applicative` can't be derived since before deriving via ([issue](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/13876)) because they removed `return` as part of the Monad of No Return. If you try to use `pure @Whatever` it will diverge!

Answer (score 3):

The cost of having to write the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances is paid only once, by the implementer. The cost of not having those instances, however, is borne by the users, time and time again. Consider a combinator which uses `Applicative`, such as [`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse):

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Without the superclass relationship, our choice of `f` being a `Monad` wouldn't be enough to let us use `traverse`. We'd end up needing a `Monad`-specific version of `traverse` (that is, [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:mapM)), and to switch from one to the other on the grounds of a distinction which is almost always irrelevant. Having `Applicative` as a superclass of `Monad` means we need not bother with that.